# TypeScript smooth-scrollbar package

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

Good morning community,

I have an Angular CLI project and I am trying to initialize the NPM package `smooth-scrollbar` but I don't seem to undestand what I am doing wrong here.

This is my `app.component.html`

```
...
<scrollbar>
  <div class="main-container scroll-content" id="mainContainer" data-scrollbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollbar-track scrollbar-track-y">
      <div class="scrollbar-thumb scrollbar-thumb-y"></div>
  </div>
</scrollbar>
...
```

where I have also tried

```
<div class="main-container scroll-content" id="mainContainer" data-scrollbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and my `.main-container` style is

```
.main-container, #mainContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 64px);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

and my `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import Scrollbar from 'smooth-scrollbar';
...
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
  Scrollbar.init(document.getElementById('#mainContainer'));
}
```

I also tried

```
Scrollbar.init(document.querySelector('#mainContainer'));
```

and

```
Scrollbar.init(<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#mainContainer'));
```

in all my attempts I am receiving the following `TypeError`

```
ERROR TypeError: expect element to be DOM Element, but got null
at Function.SmoothScrollbar.init (index.js:28)
...
```

What am I missing here? Thank you for your replies

**EDIT:** I solved the current issue by initializing the scrollbar in `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `constructor` (stupid part of me for initializing before DOM load) but now I am facing another problem: the `overscroll` effect won't enable!

Configurated as follows:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
const scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(document.getElementById('mainContainer'), {
  plugins: {
    overscroll: true
  }
});
scrollbar.updatePluginOptions('overscroll', {
  effect: 'glow',
  damping: 0.14,
  maxOverscroll: 300,
  glowColor: '#222a2d'
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component template does not exist yet in the constructor. You have to wait until angular creates it. Move the init logic into one of the [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), for example:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  Scrollbar.init(document.getElementById('#mainContainer'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I fixed this issue.